Is there a geometric interpretation to this complex equation?
$$
\left\vert\,{z - {\rm i}}\,\right\vert +
2\,\overline{z} - 1 = \left\vert\,{\overline{z} - {\rm i}}\,\right\vert + z + 3\,{\rm i}
$$

I tried solving this by plugging in
$z = x + y\,{\rm i}$, but I feel like that gets unnecessarily complex.
Is there a geometric interpretation that I'm missing ?.
Or some kind of factorization ?.


This is not a geometric approach, but is quit simple.
The equation is equivalent to
$$|z - i| - |\overline{z} - i| = -2 \overline{z} + 1+ z + 3i \tag 1$$
LHS is real, therefore so is RHS.
If $z=x+iy,$ the last claim is true iff $$y=-1.$$
The equation $(1)$ simplifies to
$$|x-2i|-|x|=1-x\tag 2$$

Case $x\ge0$
$(2)$ becomes $$|x-2i|=1,$$ which has no real solution $x.$

Case $x<0$
$(2)$ can be converted in a quadratic equation $$3x^2-4x-3=0.$$ only one of its solutions is negative.


The original equation has unique solution.

Thank you very much!

@Mixoftwo you're welcome.
